# Blue coloured Footer in UITableView for an iPhone Native App in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am developing an iPhone App using X-Code in objective C. I want to add a blue coloured footer (same as header) at the bottom of the table.

Can anyone help me in suggesting How this can be achieved. Also How to add a button in this footer.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *viewFotter = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [viewFotter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    return viewFotter;
}
```

But the thing is, u can't resize the button.Because it's doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

paste this code in your `.m` file also you can add image in your footerview

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 44;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *viewFotter = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [viewFotter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    UIButton *GoBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [GoBtn setTitle:@"GO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    GoBtn.frame = CGRectMake(85, 7, 150, 39 );
    [GoBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(GOButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewFotter addSubview:GoBtn];
    return viewFotter;
}
```

Comment: @Mayank add image if you want to set image instead of blue background, any query then ask me..

Comment: @Paras...Thanks a lot. One question I have is that will the [UIColor blueColor] will have same texture as that of the colour in Header.

Comment: no dude, if you post the image then i tell you that how can you set same as color like header but in header which color you set??

Comment: It (header) is the default one. I don't have to set any colour for it

Comment: can you post image mate?? i send you code with color code which you set in header of table other wise just set color with [UIColor colorWithRed:Blue:Green]; right mate?? i hope this help you dude...

Comment: I will try this and will get back to you. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Paras..I have added the image. I want that footer should be fixed at the bottom and should appear same as the header.

Comment: ok mate then this code is perfect you check it?? it is give same output which you want dude...

Comment: ..No mate.. it is not what I want. In the image as u can see footer is adjacent to header. I want it to be at bottom.

Comment: oh mate above which you see is NavigationBar dude.. and if you have data means raw more then one in table the check it mate its go bottom here its appear bcoz here no one raw displayed and mate above you see is NavigationBar with title Enquiries so here you just add some raw like in this method -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return 1;

}

Comment: and set color like this    [viewFotter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:141/255 green:159/255 blue:182/255 alpha:1.0]]; but first add some raws mate and if required the refer some tutorial about UITableView , you want a links and tutorial for this??

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 40;
  }

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
            UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
            footerView.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setTitle:@"BUTTON" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 5, 100, 30 );
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [footerView addSubview:btn];
            return footerView;
    }

   -(void) btnClicked:(id) sender{
     //ur code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view with the components you want (`UIButton`, `UIImageView`, etc) and set the required values in 
    `-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Or you could just assign the same view to tableFooterView

> tableView.tableFooterView = yourBlueView;

Comment: Hi Vidya Can you give an example How we can do that. I am new to iPhone app development

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button by just dragging the `UIButton` to the footer of the `UITableView` in xib.But you can't resize the button as it will automatically assigns to the table view's width.
But I don't understand what you are saying regarding footer color.Can you pls elaborate it.

Comment: I am using storyboards and I dont have xib in my project.